The term watched tags changed to "Following" which conflicts with the already used followed posts
I noticed that in last few days, the [watched-tags] that was previously shown at the top-left side of the page has been changed to [Following]. This is confusing because we already have something called "Following" in our profile page's Activity tab which shows us the posts that we are following.
So I think changing [watched-tags] to [Following] as shown in the screenshot below should be corrected.
Here is the screenshot of before this update:


And below is the screenshot of what is currently the case:


Below is the screenshot showing that we already have "Following" in our profile tab:

This is related to the sign-up experiments related to tags

I see, last couple of days I've seen other changes as well in the [watched-tags].

FYI, we use our red pens for freehand circles not text 'round here.

@philipxy Yup, was in a hurry and didn't have the pen have with me. So as long as this shows the intent it should be okay.

I will squint & try my best.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I see, but still "Following" should not be used in place of "Watched-tags"

@user12002570 I think they mean the "changing [watched-tags] to [Following]" should be undone but their current phrasing is not clear.

Only if SE were to work on implementing some real issues like two-factor authentication & adding security log options instead of doing these unnecessary cosmetic changes.

I don't particularly see the issue. Of course you can "follow" individual posts and also tags by separate systems. But the profile page should be explicit about which it means.
